# Java regular expression to validate a username with multiple criteria

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Java regular expression to validate a username
with these multiple criteria:

- minimum 3 alpha characters.
- allow numeric characters.
- no special characters but space, dot, apostrophe are allowed.
- character/dot/space/apostrophe not repeated more than 2 times:
  `a...`, `aaa`, `bbb`, `a'''`,

I tried this regex:

`^(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?=[^a-zA-Z]*(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*){3,})[a-zA-Z0-9]([.'\ha-zA-Z0-9]){2,}$`

I wrote this regular expression but it is not working:

`^(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*){3,})[a-zA-Z]([.'\ha-zA-Z]){2,}$`

It's not working in the below scenario:

"Nanni 555" -- seems that the above regexp is not accepting same numeric more than 2 times.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: it is failing "Nani N9 Test"

Comment: ^(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?=[^a-zA-Z]*(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*){3,})[a-zA-Z]([.'\ha-zA-Z]){2,}$ -- this is working for all critieria, except numeric

Comment: So we need regexp to allow numerics also. Could you please suggets

Comment: Have you tried the _\d_, or _[0-9]_ constructs?

Comment: It would be great if you could make your question clear to read, with sentences, bullet points, correct formatting, for all the readers. I think I understood it anyway and gave you my answer, but please enhance your question for all the community, as I personally find your question very interesting and helpful for a lot of other developers needing to validate some input with multiple conditions.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest some little changes/improvements:

- It's allowed to have a letter or a number repeated twice, as in
  your question, **but for spaces, dots and apostrophes, I would not
  allow any repetition**. I don't see the point of validating
  `tom..cruise`, `O''Reilly` or `Jack  Jones` (two spaces in between
  instead of one).
- It's **not allowed to start or end with a space or a dot**.

By the way, a question regarding numbers:
**Why allowing `James 007` but not `Knight 2000`?**
I applied the "*allow twice, but not more*" on numbers as you
requested, but I would personally only apply it on letters.

To make the regular expression more readable, I used the **x** flag.
This way I can put some comments in the regular expression. To match
the space char, you can either use `\`  or `\x20`. I used the first one.

I also used named groups instead of indexed groups, as most regex
engines allow it now.

The commented regular expression:

```
/
^
# The name should have at least 3 alpha characters in it:
(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){3,})
# Any letter or number should not be repeated more than twice:
(?!.*?(?<alphanum>[a-z0-9])\k<alphanum>{2})
# Any space, dot or apostrophe should not be repeated:
(?!.*?(?<ponctuationchars>[.'\ ])\k<ponctuationchars>)
# Should not start or end with a space or a dot:
(?![.\ ]|.*?[.\ ]$)
# The allowed chars are letters, numbers, space, dot and
# apostrophe. Min length is 3 in any case:
[a-z0-9\ .']{3,}
$
/ix
```

In action, with the regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/TAULpE/1

As you now see how to add multiple conditions with positive or
negative lookaheads, you can apply some changes quite easily,
especially because the commented regex doesn't get a long horizontal
unreadable pattern.

Typically, what you could change/add:

- Add some other valid chars, such as `-` for names like
  `Jean-Pierre` or `´` for `O´Reilly`. But this is a matter of
  choice.
- Accept accented chars like `é` in `Hélène`. This could be done
  by replacing `[a-z]` by `\p{L}` with the **u**nicode flag to match
  any letter in any language.
- Accept numbers more than twice and only apply this rule to letters.

This is what we finally get:

```
/
^
# The name should have at least 3 alpha characters in it:
(?=(?:.*?\p{L}){3,})
# Any letter or number should not be repeated more than twice:
(?!.*?(?<alpha>\p{L})\k<alpha>{2})
# Any space, dot, apostrophe or hyphen should not be repeated:
(?!.*?(?<ponctuationchars>[.'´\ -])\k<ponctuationchars>)
# Should not start or end with a space or a dot:
(?![.\ ]|.*?[.\ ]$)
# The allowed chars are letters, numbers, space, dot, hyphen and
# apostrophes. Min length is 3 in any case:
[\p{L}0-9\ .'´-]{3,}
$
/ix
```

In action: https://regex101.com/r/TAULpE/2